# Amazon CloudFront returning 403 using signed URLS

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, boto3

So I've been stuck on this issue for quite a while now. I've been trying to set up private access to s3 resources using CloudFront signed URLS but I'm constantly getting the following in return.

Request:

```
GET /index.html?Expires=1483228800&Signature=lhsrX7PhDWB55DUgv4kWHE9iAn1oamnus3RfDvb~X3EEAGwoEPLcMpXho~Pss2gSDTSUDFRSllZfvV3EOlOQMhixY9D036nx0rMYsqiSnl09jgKypVZGYcVVlPFqr-8~h2fduC2QjDjakMicM1TvQehCAat1cZGh1bp68KZQKO5iBiyw52xkYyvkVdUjN1l1m0W6-dnTWEOZWQIOlIX6bV8l0GHUwOpwjeQA28-bA2X7wwGeAXvYkGs5YIamBWi98O-z44vXq8k4o1d8Ce8WqLCRdoHbC6WHgOvrx9uhDQwzXIYq2u1OboJe3i8ojWKwKcGYUoR-TbBbcz3Idzfflw__&Key-Pair-Id=APKAI5QZNATBCXWPT7LA HTTP/1.1
Host: d6x4svdsauc7c.cloudfront.net
Cache-Control: no-cache
```

Response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Error><Code>AccessDenied</Code><Message>Access denied</Message></Error>

content-length →110
content-type →text/xml
date →Mon, 21 Nov 2016 15:51:13 GMT
server →CloudFront
status →403
via →1.1 940b367f846b05ee5d0f25268ff80731.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
x-amz-cf-id →rbSd5kfPq3fn0TbI-asrdZcweOFubqVqhEl28AytWgrva6wZiJZclQ==
x-cache →Error from cloudfront
```

Request:

```
GET /8994c9b6-933e-4016-a5bd-cc6c9720b170/9ccc0c6e-e1c5-4448-91a6-7899f2ebc67a.jpeg?Expires=1483228800&Signature=LreSylF4zpo3ZxXSzShTl44emepfLGHyHssSC0GvPf99TDDwytAWk4l8NtPteyU-cY679nZPFIIVtijshP99hs5kmpNyqqH~24pfE681bPLsQ8~~YeKVNmY5otgr6Ov2FYFWpR5i5uH6weja494isQsoe~2hk6-2ryqCowrKFrO2XyAjNfsP3A~VPT3REGlOL3LcA3A4rbK1H2VL9f8HVxmaL56qny7S4uXAfNaMWhEXuxFyZIaFIAotaVNYxNW5265vwUWPxcUvG4dib7YW2ZzfaEHbNngjbLJBzO~4jjAz8bw-Tj~LX45bF2gSN-JLXdESthyiI8plg65a758gPQ__&Key-Pair-Id=APKAI5QZNATBCXWPT7LA HTTP/1.1
Host: d6x4svdsauc7c.cloudfront.net
Cache-Control: no-cache
```

Response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Error><Code>AccessDenied</Code><Message>Access denied</Message></Error>

content-length →110
content-type →text/xml
date →Mon, 21 Nov 2016 15:53:15 GMT
server →CloudFront
status →403
via →1.1 940b367f846b05ee5d0f25268ff80731.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
x-amz-cf-id →93RY4Sv7dQgsFBMJG8UOEOXKhq06kc6MgpqueR_NeHyl3916kH5gwQ==
x-cache →Error from cloudfront
```

My bucket policy looks like, I've removed the name of my bucket and the Origin Access Identity ID:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "Policy1479136763703",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::cloudfront:user/CloudFront Origin Access Identity myidhere"
            },
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3::mybucket/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

As you can see I'm always getting a 403 back. When I turn off signed urls it all works as expected. I'm using Python to sign the urls. My code is pretty much the same as the example code found  [here](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/cloudfront.html#examples). Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: In your URL, I see `&amp;` where it should be simply `&`.  That may not be the only problem, but it's definitely incorrect.

Comment: My bad, I exported my requests using Postman and apparently it replaces `&` by `&amp;`. I've edited the post to reflect this. Thank you for noticing!